# Navbar that changes div contents all in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So to be quick and to the point, I'm attempting to create a small vertical menu on the left side of my screen where when you click on an item in the list, it changes all the contents of a div to the right of it, the 'content' section **but without changing the physical html file.**  Meaning, I'd like to keep it all as one document and do it with JavaScript as I've seen used before.

Here's a 'mock-up' of what I'd like to do:

[image: diagram of what the intent is]

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Alright so I've found a solution that works, but I've got 2 things I want to change with it and I'm not sure how.

```
          function toggle_visibility(id) {
                 var e = document.getElementById(id);
                 if(e.style.display == 'block')
                        e.style.display = 'none';
                 else
                        e.style.display = 'block';
            }
```

I want to add the following:

1. Only one can display at a time
2. Some sort of 'slide' animation for
   changing 'screens'

Here's an example currently on how the links work:

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('2');">Testing</a>

<div style="display:none;" id="2">
testing for page 2
</div>
```

Comment: You could use anchors and have it scroll in the div if thats what you're looking for

Comment: if it's not the scrolling on one page what you want, then you should have a look into AJAX

Comment: @Keith No it's not the scrolling, I want to 'switch' the displayed contents. So it act's like its multiple pages but I keep it to one.

Comment: i can whip up something real quick, give me a sec

Comment: Page pagination

Comment: Have you done any research? This is a common pattern that's been done many times. You'll want to research how to use ajax.

Comment: If it's static information, then maybe all you need is hide/show functionality?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ajax is not needed

Comment: Or Jquery toggle() to show hide divs onclick

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith You're right, but it is one way of doing it. It's arguably more helpful than "Page pagination"... :P

Comment: Why does this keep getting downvoted?... This question literally banned my account from asking questions because people down voted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Vanilla JavaScript is good enough for this

```js
document.querySelectorAll('nav a')
  .forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', _ => change(e.dataset.id)))


function change(n) {
  let panels = document.querySelectorAll('main div')
  panels.forEach(p => p.classList.remove('active'))
  panels[n - 1].classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: seagreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav a {
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: gold;
  display: block;
}
main div {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <nav>
    <a data-id="1">Item 1</a>
    <a data-id="2">Item 2</a>
    <a data-id="3">Item 3</a>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="active">Item 1 Content</div>
    <div>Item 2 Content</div>
    <div>Item 3 Content</div>
  </main>

</div>
```

Comment: I can just for whatever reason not get this to work. Should I update the post with the code I've got using your answer?

Comment: Alright well to test it in general I made a new simple html page and literally copy and pasted your code into it, the CSS, Java, and HTML letter for letter and it still won't work. It displays Item 1 but when I click on the others it wont switch to them. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippet is fine; it's just that the JavaScript needs to be moved to the end of the HTML. See here: [document.querySelector doesn't work in .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147320/document-queryselector-doesnt-work-in-js-file)
This is the simplest and best example of this on the Internet, so let's look at the full answer to save time for others viewing this post.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

.container {
  display: flex;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: seagreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav a {
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: gold;
  display: block;
}
main div {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>    
<div class="container">    
  <nav>
    <a data-id="1">Item 1</a>
    <a data-id="2">Item 2</a>
    <a data-id="3">Item 3</a>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="active">Item 1 Content</div>
    <div>Item 2 Content</div>
    <div>Item 3 Content</div>
  </main>

</div>    

 <script type="text/javascript">    
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
document.querySelectorAll('nav a')
.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', _ => change(e.dataset.id)));    

function change(n) {
  let panels = document.querySelectorAll('main div');
  panels.forEach(p => p.classList.remove('active'));
  panels[n - 1].classList.add('active');
}    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```