# document.querySelector doesn't work in .js file

Tags: javascript, html

If `var raster = document.querySelector ("canvas")` is in the HTML file, raster is defined and declared.  However, I'd like to have everything in my js file, only function calls in my HTML.  When I try putting `var raster...` in the .js file, it keeps coming up `null`.

Is there any way to have `document.querySelector` point to the associated HTML file?

```
// this doesn't work
//var raster = document.querySelector ("canvas").getContext ("2d");

function drawSquare (w,h) {

raster.fillStyle = "blue";
raster.fillRect (0,0,w,h);
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>IFS</title>
        <script src="IFS.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <script>var raster = document.querySelector ("canvas").getContext ("2d");
        drawSquare (500,500);</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is IFS.js?

Comment: Sorry.  The top code block is a copy-paste from the file IFS.js.  The bottom block is IFS.html.

Comment: Your script file is in the head, the element is in the body, when you put your javascript in the head, the element doesn't yet exist when it's trying to find the element in the body.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try moving `<script src="IFS.js"></script>` to the end of the HTML code, before the closing `<body>` tag, instead of having it at the `<head>`.

The issue is caused because the script is loaded before the `<canvas>` is rendered, so `document.querySelector ("canvas")` returns `null`.

Comment: I doubt that. Nothing in IFS.js is immediately dependent on the document.

Comment: Putting src="IFS.js" after canvas but before the drawSquare call worked.

Thanks very much, this is very educational!  So JavaScript parses as it goes, doesn't compile.  I see now.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses `document.querySelector("canvas")` isn't in IFS.js and does already follow `<canvas>`.

Comment: Oh, I moved it, too.  Forgot to mention that.  As it stands now: var raster is in the js file, not the HTML, and the js file is defined after canvas but before the drawSquare call.

Comment: @failure Generally, Javascript needs to come after, time-wise, the things it effects. So if you're immediately executing the Javascript (which you are) the javascript needs to be in the code after the elements it effects.